# Trouble using existing .wallet with MultiBit HD

Tags: wallet, multibit

I have an existing .wallet on my PC. I want to use this with MultiBit HD. Is it possible to use this wallet instead of creating a new one?

Comment: What software did you use to create the original .wallet file?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the two versions use two different types of key management systems.

Multibit HD is hierarchical deterministic key management. All keys generated can be recovered from a seed since the keys are generated deterministicly.

Older multibit clients used single key management where you could not recover all keys unless you had a back up of your wallet or private key.